# rails VueJS, component dissapear when navigate to other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

i am using full rails (frontend + backend) with a mixture of VueJS component in the frontend.

when i click away from 1st page to 2nd page (other controller page), the Vue component in the first page will disappear at a short glimpse. this kind of messed up some front-end view for the rails app.

v-cloak option is not feasible because that is to prevent curly braces view when page is loading. in my case is when i navigate away from the page. thansk.

Answer (score 1):

Some of this is unavoidable. When you have full page reloads (without using a client side router) you are forcing the Vue components on that page to have to be totally re-mounted and re-rendered.

The fixes are:

- A: Close to what you were getting at, hide loading of these sorts of elements behind a spinner so that they're less jarring to the user.
- B: Use a client side router.

Luckily, Rails does come with turbolinks which acts similar to a client side router. You could use turbolinks to probably help the situation, but you still might see some flashing sometimes. I really recommend being clever with how you hide loading assets as well.